# Asymmetry of (Some (x), None).min and max

Tags: scala, option-type, scala-option

Accidentally, I observed an asymmetry.

Let's have a list:

```
val li = List (Some (3), Some (2), None, Some (9)) 
li: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(3), Some(2), None, Some(9))

scala> li.max
res54: Option[Int] = Some(9)
```

Ok - Some(9) is bigger than None. Why? A convention? Is None converted to Null and Null autoboxed into a 0?

```
scala> li.min
res55: Option[Int] = None
```

Looks, as if that impression is true, but let's introduce a negative number:

```
scala> val li = List (Some (3), Some (-2), None, Some (9)) 
li: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(3), Some(-2), None, Some(9))

scala> li.min
res52: Option[Int] = None

scala> li.max
res53: Option[Int] = Some(9)
```

That's surprising, at least for me.

Yes, I know, I'm doing it wrong. The right way to go is, to flatten first, and everything is fine:

```
scala> li.flatten.min
res57: Int = -2

scala> val li = List (Some (3), Some (2), None, Some (9)) 
li: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(3), Some(2), None, Some(9))

scala> li.flatten.min
res56: Int = 2
```

But my question is still open:

Are None and Some (x), lacking other comparabilities, regarded as Objects, and then by toString compared ('N' < 'S')?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L336-L346):

```
  trait OptionOrdering[T] extends Ordering[Option[T]] {
    def optionOrdering: Ordering[T]
    def compare(x: Option[T], y: Option[T]) = (x, y) match {
      case (None, None)       => 0
      case (None, _)          => -1
      case (_, None)          => 1
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) => optionOrdering.compare(x, y)
    }
  }
  implicit def Option[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[Option[T]] =
    new OptionOrdering[T] { val optionOrdering = ord }
```

`Some(x)` is *always* treated as greater than `None`. There is no attempt to treat `None` as zero or anything else. It will therefore always be the minimum of a collection of `Option[A]`, for any `A` (assuming said collection contains `None`). There's no asymmetry in that, it's just the convention. I don't think it would really make sense to try to convert `None` to an arbitrary number for the comparison, so having `None` be less than every `Some(x)` makes sense. Otherwise, you'd need a special `Ordering[Option[A]]` for every `Ordering[A]` to handle those special cases, instead of the above generic code.